# AWS EC2 User Data to run python script is not working

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am trying to run a python script on EC2 Linux machine. All I want is on every start of the instance it should run this python script/file called my_file.py. it's in my ec2-user directory. I also tried running manually and it works fine by running the command 'python3 my_file.py'.

I have been following how to write user data from this article https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/execute-user-data-ec2/

My user data code :

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
python3 /home/ec2-user/my_file.py
--//--
```

I don't see this file running on the startup of this instance. I tried to see /var/log/cloud-init-output.log file but can't print it due to a Permission denied issue. Attaching a picture here. Not sure what's the issue or am I missing something here. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You need to elevate your permission to print cloud-init-output content. You can run `sudo su` to elevate to root user.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ErvinSzilagyi , that's exactly what I need to trace back to my issue. Now it is solved. kudos!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sudo -i` at the start of the script or else you have to use the script as a root user to execute a command